# Downloading ArcGIS Feature Service layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, feature-service

I am trying to download a dataset that I have successfully downloaded in the past using the ArcGIS Feature Service icon in the browser panel in QGIS 3.16.1. However there does not seem be an option that allows you to do this in QGIS 3.22.13. I am guessing there may be something that I am missing as it seems unlikely that the QGIS developers would remove the ability to access data via an ArcGIS Feature Service.

Comment: fyi ArcGis Feature Service” and “ArcGIS Map Service” browser connections have been replaced with a single, unified, “ArcGIS Rest Servers” (at v3.18) https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-unify-arcgis-feature-service-and-arcgis-map-service-connections-in-browser

Comment: Okay so it seems I had to enter in the URL of the feature service slightly differently for it to work with the ArcGIS Rest Servers icon.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to use "ArcGIS Rest Servers" instead and I had to enter the URL of the feature service slightly differently.